# Does register #30 ($fp) have anything to do with the jal function in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, instructions

"`jal Rout` is the instruction which is executed by the MIPS processor and is located in the address `0x00400100`. The label `Rout` is points to a subroutine which is located in the address `0x00555500`. What will be the value of register #30 (`$fp`, frame pointer) after the execution of the `jal Rout` instruction?"

To my understanding, it won't be altered, since the `$fp` is not used by `jal`, it instead uses register #31 (`$ra`, return address). Am I wrong? Is there something more to this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and asking and reading various references, the conclusion was that, indeed, `jal` affects the `$ra` register, not the `$fp`, therefore the various addresses and the rest of this question are useless; the answer is "**`jal` doesn't affect the register number 30**".

Comment: Debug builds may contain code to set up a stack frame, but that's optional and just a software convention.  Nothing to do with how the MIPS ISA works.  And the choice of `$30` as `$fp` is arbitrary; any other register number would have been an equally good choice for the calling convention.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'm afraid my knowledge on MIPS assembly is not as vast. Good addition.